# When I post a request through rest template,It throws no suitable HttpMessageConverter

Tags: java, spring, xmlhttprequest, resttemplate, httpentity

```
HttpHeaders reqheaders= new HttpHeaders();
reqheaders.set(HttpHeaders.Accept,MediaType.Application_xml)
reqheaders.set(HttpHeaders.Content_type,MediaType.Application Json)
HttpEntity XML= new HttpEntity (json,reqheaders)
ResponseEntity<Map> xmlfile= restTemplate.exchange(url,HttpMethod.POST,XML, Map.class)
```

I am getting **no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type[interface java.util.Map] and content type [application/xml;charset=UTF-8]**

Answer (score 0):

it looks like no suitable `HttpMessageConverter` is registered with the RestTemplate can convert `xml` content to a Map object.

There some `HttpMessageConverters` which are pre-enabled and can be checked [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest). You need to make sure that the suitable `HttpMessageConverter` is on your classpath.